# How can I dispose of an arbitrary dependency when a stream is disposed?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a .NET API and one of my methods returns a `Stream`. I need to ensure that some other class is disposed when the caller disposes the `Stream` that I return.

The only way I can think to do this is to create a wrapper class that inherits from `Stream` and tacks on the functionality I need, delegating everything else to the underlying `Stream`.

I don't like having to decorate a framework class simply because it may get new members in future .NET releases that I would need to update my API to support.

Is there a better way to do this?

### Example

Here is a concrete example for your pondering.

Keep in mind that one of the requirements of this class is that it cannot require disposal, referring to the `ContentSource` class in the example.

```
public class ContentSource
{
    public Stream OpenRead()
    {
        var entry = GetEntry();

        // TODO: Ensure that when the stream we return is disposed, we also dispose of `entry.Archive`.
        return entry.Open();
    }

    private ZipArchiveEntry GetEntry()
    {
        ZipArchive archive = null;
        try
        {
            archive = new ZipArchive(_zipContent.OpenRead(), ZipArchiveMode.Read, false);
            var entry = archive.GetEntry(_entryName);
            if (entry == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified entry was not found in the ZIP archive. " + _entryName);
            }

            return entry;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (archive != null)
            {
                archive.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Stream Wrapper Example

This is the solution I can think of that I'm not happy with.

```
public sealed class DependencyDisposingStreamWrapper : Stream
{

    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly IDisposable _dependency;
    private bool _disposed;

    public DependencyDisposingStreamWrapper(Stream stream, IDisposable dependency)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    # region - Overrides of all Stream members, delegating to underlying stream -

    // ...

    #endregion

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dependency.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "Keep in mind that one of the requirements of this class is that it cannot require disposal" - Why is that a requirement?

Comment: The inability to require disposal incompatible with using streams.

Comment: Also, in this example, instead of disposing the Stream and needing a mechanism to dispose ZipArchive, wouldn't you just dispose ZipArchive, which in turn would automatically dispose the Stream?

Comment: The return of the `Open()` method (the `Stream`) can/will require disposal. We just don't want to require the `ContentSource` to be disposed. It will be used in part via PowerShell and PS doesn't have a nice workflow for ensuring objects are disposed, especially when you work with them in a pipeline. We want `Open()` to simply lazily open the stream and then clean up after itself when the returned stream is disposed.

Comment: @mbeckish - In reality we are implementing an interface that dictates the `Open()` method return a `Stream` so we can't return the `ZipArchive`. Where the `Stream` comes from is meant to be hidden from the caller.

Comment: Can you change your API to program against an interface rather than a Stream implementation?  You could define the interface to be IDisposable and have an Open() method.

Comment: Types that wrap/inherit Stream should themselves implement IDisposable, and their Dispose method should Dispose the Stream.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Yes... I'm not sure how this relates to the topic. The `Stream`, and my `StreamWrapper` class will both be `IDisposable` and the wrapper will dispose the underlying `Stream`.

Comment: @mbeckish - Not a bad idea. Basically just push that `Stream` down a level. That might work for this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composition instead of inheritance?

That's how the .Net does it for items like, say, StreamReader. There's a member property for the base stream, rather than inheriting from stream.

If want to work with the existing types like StreamReader/Writer, TCPClient, etc, you'll be stuck inheriting Stream, though.

Comment: Composition is a good point. Thanks! I don't think it'll work for this particular use case as I want to maintain compatibility with other classes that take `Stream` but could work for other cases.

Comment: The OP's solution *is* composition.  He's using `Stream` as if it were an interface, essentially.  (I almost wish it were, to be honest).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the closest to what I ended up doing. Thanks to you and @mbeckish I ended up creating an equivelant of `StreamReader` that wraps things up nicely and allows the caller to access the base stream via a `BaseStream` property. I'm much happier with this than wrapping `Stream` directly... that would have been such a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a wrapper.  There is no means of being notified when the stream is disposed.  Some other types may provide a public event that is fired when they are disposed, but `Stream` doesn't.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the case but figured I'd throw it out here in case there is a better pattern that I'm not aware of for dealing with this case. Thanks!